# My simple lambda function is returning null for s3 listbucket. What could I be doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am just trying basic list all my buckets, but its not firing, any idea what i might be doing wrong?

```
'use strict';
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

module.exports.hello = async (event, context) => {
  // console.log("hi yall");
  // return "hello";
  var params = {};
 s3.listBuckets(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
 });

};
```

return value is null and the following is my log output

START RequestId: 827acca9-3e91-405d-a031-7fac249284a0 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 827acca9-3e91-405d-a031-7fac249284a0
REPORT RequestId: 827acca9-3e91-405d-a031-7fac249284a0  Duration: 45.66 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 31 MB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use async you should promisify the AWS function and await it like this:

```
   'use strict';
   var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
   var s3 = new AWS.S3();

   module.exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

     var params = {};
     let data = await s3.listBuckets(params).promise();
     console.log(data); 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 s3.listBuckets(function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); 
   else     console.log(data);           
 });
```

Have you set properly AWS settings?

Comment: @lwko that code piece doesn't work either, same result.  By AWS settings you mean iam role? when i run the code localy by invoking node handler.js it works and i get list of buckets, but in lambda it doesnt

Comment: @user2763557 you need to specify  credentials and region in configuration like here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/configuring-the-jssdk.html

Comment: I have set both of these, any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. One should remove async and it works, not sure why but it does work now. If someone can drop the explanation here that would be great!